# Ignoring a specific Exception raised within a third party sdk

Tags: android

I've integrated a third party sdk and it causing the app to crash for some users. I am just wondering is it possible to ignore a certain type of Exception and continue the app execution.

I tried the `UncaughtExceptionHandler` but it causes the app to halt after the exception. Tried calling `Looper.loop()` in UncaughtExceptionHandler to continue and it works for the first exception. Any exceptions raised afterwards will still cause the app to halt.